# pound character(#) in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

in below code; it gets a content of a "div" includes html codes, and it saves at ajsave.php. But when div html contents include "#" character, data is shorted after "#" like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "ajsave.php", 
    data: "usr="+id+"&divcontent="+cont, 
    success: function(msg){
        $("#result").html(msg); 
}});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a URL the `#` character is used to designate an anchor - part of the page that you want to move the page to - so is ignored by your web server. In order to fix this, you'll need to escape it on the client-side (in your JavaScript code) using the [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function, and then unescape it on the server.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the # is to define the anchor in the page so it is removed... I would suggest you use POST instead of GET, it will correct your problem and prevent some more. If you still want to have it in GET, do this:

```
cont = cont.replace("#","%22");
```

Comment: the pound character "#" can be URL encoded as "%23". the above mentioned "%22" would decode to the double quote sign